# Is there no manual page for /dev (devfs)?

Tags: debian, man

I have been looking for a `man` page for the `/dev` (`devfs`) filesystem in order to understand the various directories and files within.

Currently, I've only found a related `man` page for `/proc` (`procfs`).

Is there any (`man`) documentation available for `devfs`? How can I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`devfs` is obsolete and was removed in kernel 2.6.18](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/removed/devfs). Nowadays `/dev` is typically a [`devtmpfs`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/devtmpfs.c), but that’s not documented.

The *contents* of `/dev` are described in the various device manpages [in section 4](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_4.html); for example, `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are documented in [`random(4)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html). The canonical reference for the nodes in `/dev` on Linux is [the list of allocated devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html).

File systems are normally documented [in section 5](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_4.html); you’ll also find documentation of file systems [in the corresponding section of the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/#filesystems).

Comment: Thank you. Why do you refer to the contents of `/dev` as “nodes”? Any specific reason?

Comment: They’re created with `mknod`, “make node”, I’ve always thought of them as nodes rather than “special files”.

Answer (score 1):

You're not interested in the devfs which has been deprecated for a long time. What you're interested in are various devices contained within:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html

https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha-udev.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Device_file